# $3^a\cdot X+3^{a-1}=2^{b}-2^{c}$ proof for odd integers

Tags: number-theory

Can we prove that for all odd integers X>0, there is a least one triple of integers (a,b,c) such as the following equation is true:

$3^a\cdot X+3^{a-1}=2^{b}-2^{c}$

I seem to be able to find some conditions for which the equation above is true but any hints welcome.

Edit - closing this thread as I realized I made a stupid mistake.
Here is the equation I wanted a proof for

$3^a\cdot X+3^{a-1}=2^{b}-2c$

Comment: Do you mean at least one triple $(a,b,c)$?

Comment: I would write it as $(3X+1)3^{a-1}=2^b-2^c$.  The factor $3^{a-1}$ will force $b-c$ to be a multiple $2\cdot 3^{a-2}$

Comment: where did you find this question?

Comment: Very true@RossMillikan, this factorization is useful. Playing with the right hand part too, for example factoring out $2^{c}(Y-1)$, on can identify condition on b-c to be a multiple of 3.
@Gon personal incursion into Collatz conjecture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result would appear not to be true:

Let $X=7$, and suppose $22\times 3^{a-1}=2^b-2^c$, for some $a,b,c$.

Then $c=1$ and $11\times 3^{a-1}=2^{b-1}-1.$

Considering this equation modulo $11$,  we see that $b-1$ must be a multiple of $10$ but then $2^{b-1}$ is also a multiple of $31$.